# Executar função javascript em chamadas AJAX para uma página específica

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Tenho um site em Laravel onde o conteúdo é carregado dinamicamente com AJAX, ou seja, em cada chamado o Laravel retorna apenas a view da parte que eu necessito, em uma determinada página eu preciso inicializar um plugin jQuery que só uso nessa página.
Se eu inicializar esse plugin em todas as chamadas vai funcionar, mas eu vou acabar criando uma sobrecarga desnecessária.
Qual é o melhor método de passar essa chamada de função JS quando eu a chamada para tal página acontecer?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando ou implementando alguma library de lazy load, que carrega os scripts sob demanda.

Que tal algo como:

```
myLib.load(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'fancybox'], function(){
    // Isso aqui só vai rodar quando as 3 dependências forem carregadas
});
```